# Help with substitute components for LWC conversion

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am converting an existing application to work under LWC, however, I have hit a couple of snags.

The existing app uses an HTML editor called froala, and it uses a calendar component called fullcalendar.
I had a look at the existing LWC lightning-input-rich-text, which seems to be a wrapper around Quill JS, however, it just doesn't have enough functionality for our needs. For example, resizing images, reliable DnD of images.

Also, there doesn't seem to be a suitable calendar control that I can control things like the color (individually) of events, the source of events, drag and drop from off calendar and within calendar too that I have with fullcalendar.

Is there a marketplace for LWC components where I could perhaps look to see if there are better versions that the native controls? Or do you know of something that would match my needs?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a marketplace for LWC. But you can use third-party libraries like `fullcalendar` and `quilljs` which gives you full control.

For `fullcalendar` you can get code from [this](https://github.com/Gurenax/sfdx-lwc-fullcalendarjs) git repo (not owned by me).

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) is how you can use third-party libraries in LWC.